# GNU Readline Histfile "write_history()" Problems

Tags: c, readline

I need help with the function `write_history()` in Readline for C.

I've been trying to make it so in a test program. For example, it would make a file, read the file (read the history found in the file), take user input using `readline()`, then write to the file (The history).
But, I've found that every time that `write_history()` is run, it overwrites the older file. And I can't seem to file how to make `write_history()` not overwrite the previous file.

Here's some *example* code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <readline/readline.h>
    #include <readline/history.h>
    
    int
    main()
    {
        FILE *hist;
        hist = fopen("./test.hist", "w");
        fclose(hist);
        while (1) {
            char *text;
            read_history("./test.hist");
            text = readline("> ");
            add_history(text);
            free(text);
            write_history("./test.hist");
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: You are writing to the same file name that had been passed to `read_history`.

Comment: You don't describe what behavior you want instead. For example, you could move the old history file into a new location before calling `write_history`. Or perhaps you want to use `append_history` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> But, I've found that every time that write_history() is run, it
> overwrites the older file.

Yes, indeed. That's exactly what the [manual page](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#History-Functions) for `write_history ()` specifies:

> Function: `int write_history (const char *filename)` - Write the current
> history to filename, **overwriting filename if necessary**. If filename is
> NULL, then write the history list to ~/.history. Returns 0 on success,
> or errno on a read or write error.

Perhaps OP is looking for `append_history ()` - @jxh:

> Function: `int append_history (int nelements, const char *filename)` -
> Append the last nelements of the history list to filename. If filename
> is NULL, then append to ~/.history. Returns 0 on success, or errno on
> a read or write error.